# How to run my Complete Web Application Project on target Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, publishing

I am working on Current Web Application and i want to make .exe/dll/msi thing that the project will run on target machine without source code.

Anyone have a solution for this that i have to give the build of my project without giving source code to it.

Can we create a .exe of web application?

Comment: Working on a web application without knowing if it can be an exe or not ?? I fear what that web app shall be.

Comment: client have to test my web application. So i want to give something like build/.exe to run on their machine and i dont want to give public access too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish your web application on web server, and let the target machine access it via url.

Comment: i dont want to give a public access.. what should i do when there is no internet connection.?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I get it, but you could just sending the build of the webapp to your target server. Have a look at deploying web app: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53075/How-to-deploy-ASP-NET-Web-Application-on-server

Answer (score 0):

dude i have discussed your issue with some of system Admin frnds

your problem solution at host level deploy your site restrict public access and add ip on local machine

Comment: hey dear i dont want to give public access before final completion of my project.

Comment: this is what i have suggested to you , you will give purmition through your firewall to selected machine only